# Best way to create "variables" that users can use in templates with either php or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm quite wondering what the best way is to have certain variables that users can use in for example email templates. I'm not talking about PHP variables (or JavaScript variables for that matter), but I mean for example {{site.name}} which will be converted to Stack Overflow in the case of this website.

I know this is possible using for example Javascript and JQuery with the following code:

```
var body = $('.div-content');
var text = body.html();
text = text.replace('{{site.name}}','Stack Overflow');
body.html(text);
```

However this seems to be a quite unnecessary solution as this would make me having a lot of replacements with more then 1 variable, and this would cause webpages to be really slow. Is there a good way of defining such variables using PHP for example? Or is Javascript the way to go and should I enhance my current example?

I couldn't really find a good solution to this problem while searching on Google, as I don't even know if there is a special word to call those variables. Any input on this matter is really appriciated.

Comment: In the PHP side, what don't you just use a templating engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). Or are you already using one?

Comment: I have used Smarty in the past, but I'm not really a big fan of it. Mainly due to the fact that I had no experience with it at the time I used it, and I couldn't really see why I would use it in the first place. Is Smarty a really helpful on this oarticular case, or is that merely a side functinality?

Comment: I haven't used it much myself but from what I know, you give smarty a array(or associative) and a template and it does the rest. Which I think is what you want to be done. If I may ask, what PHP framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel, and I will have a look at Smarty as well, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it on the client side with JQuery you could use your own tags as templates.

An example would be the following.

Place a tag named `<sitename></sitename>` in your html body for example.

Then you could use the following Jquery to populate its value.

JQuery:

```
  //fill the sitename tag with content Stack Overflow
  $("sitename").html("Stack Overflow");
```

You could expand this example further using any tag names you like.